# Auto "accept" a pre-filled Windows 7 password prompt dialog

Tags: windows-7, password-management

I use the tray program GmailNotifier. Whenever I log on to my computer and GmailNotifier starts, it asks for a password, using this password prompt dialog. (I'm running Windows 7)

[image]

The username and password are "remembered" by Windows so I just have to hit the Enter key.

I would like to not have to press enter and just make GmailNotifer login automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will store passwords, but depending on how the program is written and the server, it may still force a prompt on you.

I know Gmail servers don't refuse stored credentials. You dont' happen to be on a work domain?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you are mismunderstanding my situation. Windows IS storing my username and password, but still forcing the prompt on me. What I would like to do is not have to press "Ok" on the prompt each time the computer starts up.